# Matlab gpuArray: cuda error already mapped

Tags: matlab, gpu

I was trying to use gpuArray, for instance with the following Matlab provided example:

```
X = rand(10, 'single');
G = gpuArray(X);
classUnderlying(G)   % Returns 'single'
G2 = G .* G;         % Performed on GPU
whos G2              % Result on GPU
```

But Matlab gives this error message. I checked online, it means the resources already mapped, which does not tell me much. How should I fix this? Previously I had no problem using gpuArray on my matlab. Thank you!

```
Error using gpuArray
An unexpected error occurred during CUDA execution. The CUDA error was:
CUDA_ERROR_ALREADY_MAPPED
```

Comment: Have you tried updating (or reinstalling) your CUDA drivers? Doing that might jiggle the bits. Do you have any other applications running (or their low level daemons)? In particular video games, 3-D graphics, or video software? Does logging out or restarting help?

Comment: This happened after I just restarted my computer. I did not reinstall my CUDA drivers, but I did reinstall matlab, would that change anything?

Comment: Did you upgrade to a new version of Matlab? Do you still have the old one? If it's not running I'm not sure if that would cause anything. Can you run `gpuDevice` and post the results or does that return an error too? I'd try reinstalling/upgrading CUDA as well as that's not very hard. And do you have more than one GPU (or onboard + dedicated as in a laptop)?

Comment: gpuDevice also returns the same error of already mapped. I have matlab 2013b and CUDA 5.5. Last time reinstall matlab was only to install a new toolbox, but the version did not change. I have two GPUs in my desktop.

Comment: You asked the same question at http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/114502-gpuarray-cuda-error-already-mapped . Some people are trying to help you there but you are not answering their question / clarifications.

Comment: Just now I reinstalled CUDA and it is fixed!